# How to make IE11 start loading iframe earlier?

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-11

It seems IE11 gives iframes lower priority, so they will start loading only after the rest of the page is loaded.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2013/12/04/getting-to-the-content-you-want-faster-in-ie11.aspx

Is there a way to override this default?

Does not look too good if you have the main content area inside an iframe that is hosted in the main page which contains header and a sidebar for selecting the active content. If the main page is slow to load then the content iframe will remain blank until it too may start loading its default startup page.

Comment: Why use an iframe in the first place? I think they're often overused: you should build a [Single Page Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) and use AJAX in most situations rather than use an iframe.

Comment: can you use js in this site? you could do an .onload clause on the iframe and then display the rest with js after.

Comment: Yes, js can be used. How would onload work here? Do you mean I should load the iframe contents in the onload handler instead of waiting for the src document to load? (I would prefer not to do anything that require big changes as this is an existing app, and this issue is not that big a deal, just slightly annoying on IE11 only.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.write('<iframe ...> ...</iframe>')` to boost the priority.

There is also another interesting hack by Jake Archibald but it's more complicated to put in place:

https://jakearchibald.com/2016/fun-hacks-faster-content/